# ¿Cómo puedo pasar una tabla de String a DOS ArraysList?

Tags: java, arraylist, tablas

Estoy haciendo un trabajo en Android Studio y necesito pasar un String que cojo de una BD el cual tiene ID#Nombre#ID#Nombre#.

Sé que con un split, puedo separar todos los componentes y así guardarlos en un ArrayList, pero no sé cómo puedo guardarlos en 2 distintas.

```
//ArrayList
ArrayList <String> nomciudades = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList <Integer> numCiudades = new ArrayList<Integer>();

//String
String txt = "1#Alava#2#Albacete#3#Alacant#4#Almeria#5#Avila#";

//tabla
String ciudades[];
```

Les pongo una variable con un ejemplo del texto que retorna la BD.

Antes únicamente me retornaba el nombre de las ciudades, por lo que ponía un bucle for y hacía add i ya, pero ahora que me retorna la ID y el nombre, no puedo hacerlo, ya que si pongo un split `ciudades = txt.split("#")` la tabla será "1,Alava,2,Albacete...".

¿Qué opciones hay para llenar las dos ArrayList?

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer, es con `split` como bien mencionas, separar todos los campos en distintas posiciones y guardarlos en un ArrayList temportal, y luego crear un bucle donde rellenas los dos que has creado con los datos del arrayList temporal, pasando los valores de uno en uno a cada uno. ¿Me epxlico?

Comment: Entiendo la idea, pero sigo sin entender el cómo llenar los otros dos Arrays con este tercero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer, es utilizar `split` para crear un Array temporal donde guardes todos los datos que quieres. Luego puedes crear un bucle en el que recorras este Array, y guardes los valores en tus dos ArrayList.

Puedes sacar el tamaño de tu ArrayList utilizando la función `.size()`, y luego crear un bucle `for` en el que asignes los dos ArrayList:

```
    ArrayList<String> nomciudades = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> numCiudades = new ArrayList<String>();

    String txt = "1#Alava#2#Albacete#3#Alacant#4#Almeria#5#Avila#";
    String[] parts = txt.split("#");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i = i + 2) {
        numCiudades.add(parts[i]);
        nomciudades.add(parts[i + 1]);
    }
```

En este caso, el segundo ArrayList lo he puesto del tipo String, pero si quieres que sea un número, simplemente deberás de hacer una conversión

Comment: Gracias, aunque uno de los ArrayList es Integer, ¿Poniendo un parseInt se podría utilizar igual?

Comment: Si, simplemente deberías de cambiar la línea por lo siguiente: `numCiudades.add(Integer.parseInt(parts[i]));` Y obviamente cambiar el tipo del ArrayList

Comment: Lo estaba probando, me ha aparecido un error que ahora añadiré a la respuesta

Comment: Fijate en el tu `for` como sumas la variable `i`. En tu caso estás sumándolo de uno en uno, en el que te he puesto yo, lo sumamos de dos en dos, ya que es la distancia que hay entre un número de un registro y el siguiente. Hacemos `i = i + 2` ya que de esta manera, la posición de la `i` siempre será el numero de la ciudad.

Comment: Ya está solucionado, no había leído bien el código. Muchas gracias.

Comment: En tal caso, marcala como solución por si alguien se encuentra con el mismo problema. Un saludo